# My reputation doesn't increase although I'm receiving many positive bookings, it stays at 432 constantly

Tags: support

Can you please have a look at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656912/romeo-kienzler)? Even if I receive reputation points, the counter constantly stays at 437.

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3656912/romeo-kienzler?tab=reputation

Comment: I assume you are asking about your SO profile - you can view your breakdown here (http://stackoverflow.com/users/3656912/romeo-kienzler?tab=reputation) - that will show you what you have gained/lost and why.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem? (also - what are bookings? Do you mean upvotes?)

Comment: [This is probably a caching issue.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)